# Tokenising / filtering text with markup

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following text:

`Lurasidone is a dopamine D<sub>2</sub>`

I would like to tokenize it such that I get the following tokens:

> Lurasidone
>
> dopamine
>
> D2

How do I achieve this using a tokenizer or filter? I've attempted to to use the html filter however `D<sub>2</sub>` is tokenized as:

> D
>
> 2

whereas I need it to tokenize as:

> D2

Comment: Can you show how you've used the `html_strip` character filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Pattern Replace Char Filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/analysis-pattern-replace-charfilter.html)

This is what I did.

```
"char_filter": {
    "html_pattern": {
        "type": "pattern_replace",
        "pattern": "<.*>(.*)<\\/.*>",
        "replacement": "$1"
    }
}
```

I included that in my `custom analyzer` like this

```
"my_custom_analyzer": {
    "tokenizer": "standard",
    "char_filter": [
        "html_pattern"
    ],
    "filter": ["stop"]
}
```

These are the tokens generated for your text

```
{
   "tokens": [
      {
         "token": "Lurasidone",
         "start_offset": 0,
         "end_offset": 10,
         "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
         "position": 1
      },
      {
         "token": "dopamine",
         "start_offset": 16,
         "end_offset": 24,
         "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
         "position": 4
      },
      {
         "token": "D2",
         "start_offset": 25,
         "end_offset": 38,
         "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
         "position": 5
      }
   ]
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: sorry, forgot to explain regex, basically I am capturing everything inside html tags and then [backreferencing](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) it. so $1 represents everything between html tags, which is  _2_ in this case